# What is the best way to backfill a partition table using data from a non partitioned table? (postgres 12)

Tags: postgresql

I'm converting a non partitioned table to a partitioned table in postgres 12. Assuming I have set up the new partition table and have created appropriate triggers for automatic creation of partitions, what is the best way to back fill the currently empty partition table?

Is a naive

```
insert into partitioned_table(a,d,b,c) select a, d, b, c  from non_partitioned_table;
delete from non_partitioned_table;
```

appropriate? We have ~250M rows in the table so am a bit concerned about doubling the storage requirements.

Or perhaps

```
WITH moved_rows AS (
    DELETE FROM non_partitioned_table
)
INSERT INTO partitioned_table
SELECT [DISTINCT] * FROM moved_rows;
```

or

```
COPY non_partitioned_table TO '/tmp/non_partitioned_table.csv' DELIMITER ',';

COPY partitioned_table FROM '/tmp/non_partitioned_table.csv' DELIMITER ',';
```

Either way seems like it could take a while to transfer the data. I'm also concerned that it will kill INSERT performance while data is being migrated so I assume we'd need to block inserts until it's done. Is there any way to estimate how long it will take to copy the data over?

Comment: Do not use a trigger on the table while you move the data, it will slow your performance considerably. Also, add constraints and indexes only after transferring the data. Yes, you'll need twice the storage, no matter what, and you'll have downtime while the transformation takes place. Set `max_wal_size` and `maintenance_work_mem` high for performance.

Comment: so I'd have to do something like insert into partitioned_table_2020_04_27(a,d,b,c) select a, d, b, c  from non_partitioned_table where timestamp > '2020-04-27' AND timestamp < '2020-04-28';
delete from non_partitioned_table where timestamp > '2020-04-27' AND timestamp < '2020-04-28';

This would be very slow as there is no index on timestamp :(

Comment: No, the data will be directed to the proper partition automatically.

Comment: Ah got it. You'd suggest precreating the partitions (perhaps using pg_pathman) instead of using triggers?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.